# Setup std::vector in class constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, new-operator, stdvector

I'm designing a class that has a `std::vector<int>` as an instance variable.  I'm using a `std::vector` because I need to set its size at runtime.  Here are the relevant portions of my code:

```
my_class.h:

#include <vector>
using std::vector;
class MyClass {
    int size;
    vector<int> vec;
}

my_class.cc:

#include "my_class.h"
using std::vector
MyClass::MyClass(int m_size) : size(m_size) {
     vec = new vector<int>(size,0);
}
```

When I attempt to compile I get these error messages:

```
g++ -c -Wall my_class.cc -o my_class.o

my_class.cc: In constructor ‘MyClass::MyClass(int):

  my_class.cc:4 error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘((MyClass*)this)->My_Class::vec = ((*(const allocator_type*)(& std::allocator<int>())), (operator new(24u), (<statement>, ((std::vector<int>*)<anonymous>))))’

make: *** [my_class.o] Error 1
```

However, when I change the offending line to:

```
vector<int> temp(size,0);
vec = temp;
```

It now compiles without a hitch and I get the desired behavior and can access my vector as

```
vec[i]  // i having been defined as an int yada yada yada
```

This workaround is okay, but I would like to understand why it works and the first method fails.

Comment: `new vector` returns a pointer not a value, for you to be able to assign it to your member variable `vec`

Comment: My guess is you come from Java or C# and if so, my serious advice is to get a good, introductory C++ book first.

Comment: And please always post actual code via the copy+paste method. The code you posted is incomplete

Comment: *Aside*: do you really need the `size` member? Recall that vectors carry around their own size, which can always be queried like so: `vec.size()`.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Just do:

```
MyClass::MyClass(int m_size) : size(m_size), vec(m_size, 0)
```

You already seem to know about initializer lists, why not initialize vector there directly?

```
vec = new vector<int>(size,0);
```

is illegal because `new` returns a pointer and in your case `vec` is an object.

Your second option:

```
vector<int> temp(size,0);
vec = temp;
```

although it compiles, does extra work for no gain. By the time you reach the assignment, two vectors would already have been constructed and discarded afterwards.

Comment: IIRC this will cause warnings with GCC because of the order of initialization - you should order the initializations in initializer list the same way as member variables in the class.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, based on it I tried doing                    vec = *(new vector<int>(szie,0));                                   and that also worked, but I will use initializer list thank you!

Comment: @user1269950 what you did is wrong - it creates a memory leak. `new` allocates a memory on the heap, creates an object there and returns a pointer to it. What you did was assign the contents of that object to your member object and then forget about the original one - but it still remains allocated forever. When you call `new` you always must save the address it returns (in a pointer) and eventually call `delete` on that pointer!

Comment: @user1269950 no, don't do `*(new...)`. Memory leak.

Answer (score 14):

The use of vector is legal in your class, the problem is how you initialize it:

```
#include <vector>

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(int m_size);

    // ... more things...
private:
    int size;
    vector<int> vec;
}
```

You are assigning a pointer to a new vector object, as if this vector object was not initialized.

```
vec = new vector<int>(size,0);
```

If you really want this to work, then you should declare your `vec` object as:

```
vector<int> * vec;
```

And don't forget to add a destructor:

```
MyClass::~MyClass {
    delete vec;
}
```

Why did it work when you dropped the `new` particle? Because you are creating a new object `vector`, and *overwriting* the one in your class (this does not guarantee the original one to be correctly eliminated, however).

You actually don't need to do that. Your `vector` object is already initialized (its default constructor called) when you've reached the constructor of MyClass. If you just want to be sure that memory is reserved for `size` items:

```
MyClass::MyClass(int m_size): size(m_size) {
    vec.reserve( size );
}
```

If you want your vector to have `size` elements, then:

```
MyClass::MyClass(int m_size): size(m_size), vec(m_size, 0)
    {}
```

Finally, as one of the commenters points out, size is not actually needed once the vector has been constructed. So you can get rid of the `size` member:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(int m_size): vec(m_size, 0)
        {}

    unsigned int getSize() const
        { return vec.size(); }

    // ... more things...
private:
    vector<int> vec;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @OP -- The `vector` knows its size, so if all `size` is doing is keeping track of the number of elements in `vector`, then suggest you get rid of `size`.

Comment: Could you please explain, why we can't put the `vec = new vector<int>(size,0);` statement in the constructor, it is showing compilation error when I am trying to do so `error: no viable overloaded '=' :  v= new vector<int>(26, -1)`. Please help!

Comment: You cannot do that because `vec` is not a pointer to a **vector** object, but a **vector** object itself. The `:vec(m_size, 0)` just initializes the **vector**, you don't need to do anything else. If you really want to create a **vector** with `new`, then change the `vec`member to be `vector<int> *vec`. And remember to eliminate it with the `delete` operator in the destructor!

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::vector;
using std::to_string;

class Parse
{
private:
    string         m_str;
    vector<string> m_vec;
public:
    // Constructor with all defaults (1 of 4 constructors)
    Parse(){ 
        cout << "\ncreating class with all default values\n";
        m_str = "";
        m_vec.push_back("");    
    }

    // Constructor with all cases used
    Parse  (string         &tmp_str,
            vector<string> tmp_vec):

            m_str          (tmp_str),
            m_vec          (tmp_vec)
    {
        cout << "Your vector contains " + to_string(m_str.size()) + " arguments\n";
    }

    // Constructor with other contents given but not vector
    Parse  (string         &tmp_str): 
            m_str          (tmp_str)
    {
        m_vec.push_back("");
    }
    // Constructor with only Vector given but not other contents
    Parse  (vector<string>   tmp_vec):
            m_vec           (tmp_vec)
    {
        m_str = "";
    }

    string get_str_var(){return m_str;}

    void classed_print_vector_strings()
    {
        for (string i : m_vec){ cout << i << " \n";}
    }

};



// rm ./class_vector; g++ class_vector.cpp -o class_vector -std=c++17; ./class_vector arg1 arg2 arg3

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // turn **argv to a vector
    vector<string> args(argv, argv + argc);
    // iterate from argv through argv+argc

    // initialize with default arguments.
    Parse tracker1;
    // initalize with all used arguments
    Parse tracker2(args[0], args);
    // initalize with only the vector
    Parse tracker3(args);
    // initalzie without the vector, but with another arg
    Parse tracker4(args[0]);

    cout << "\nTracker 1 ---------------------\n";
    tracker1.classed_print_vector_strings();
    cout << "\nTracker 2 ---------------------\n";
    tracker2.classed_print_vector_strings();
    cout << "\nTracker 3 ---------------------\n";
    tracker3.classed_print_vector_strings();
    cout << "\nTracker 4 ---------------------\n";
    tracker4.classed_print_vector_strings();


    return 0;
}
```

```sh
rm ./class_vector; g++ class_vector.cpp -o class_vector -std=c++17; ./class_vector arg1 arg2 arg3
```

This will show you how to create a class that will give
you the option to initialize the class with or without
the vector with other arguments present and/or not present.